# Execute method on android notification click

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

I need to execute a particular method in my application when the notification is clicked but I do not want to launch any activity. How do I use pending intent to successfully accomplish the same. I guess one way is to send a broadcast and let my service process it. Is there any other way to perform a background task on notification click?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a BroadcastReceiver

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: How do you send the Broadcast from the notification tray?